# C# Splitstring and Rename in SSIS Script Task

Tags: c#, ssis

Hi I have a process in place which I have inherited that moves files from one location to another based on filenames using C# within SSIS and I am looking to add some extra functionality.

I am trying to accomplish the below within SSIS using C# inside a script task and am looking for some assistance if possible.

For reference, files used always start with an ID, followed by an underscore, so for example ID123456_FileName.csv

1. Take the ID123456 part of the file name and move it to the end of the filename. So for example **ID123456_FileName.csv** would become **FileName_ID123456.csv**.

I have been looking into using splitstring to take the string from the start of the file name and then move it to the end using rename but being fairly new to this I'm hoping to get some pointers in the right direction.

The ID number will always change, but will always have an underscore after the ID number. The filename can be used as a variable.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the sample, I think you're looking for something like

```
string fileExtension = ".csv";
string originalName = "ID123456_FileName.csv";

// Generate a 2 element array with values of of ID123456 and FileName.csv
string [] nameParts = string.Split(originalName, '_');

// Using lots of local variables for debugging purposes
// TODO: Defend against "bad" names here and blind ordinal addressing

// Rip out the ID and strip the file extensions
string id = originalName[1].Replace(fileExtension, "");

// Silly yes, but now you can breakpoint on this in case you get weird results
string fname = originalName[0];

// Some people have strong feelings on string building. I do not
// No string interpolation b/c I never remember whether it works in SSIS default framework of 4.5
string finalName =  id + "_" + fname + fileExtension;
string altFinalName = string.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", id, fname, fileExtension);
```